# Complete example for Eclipse RCP 3.6.2/P2/Junit tests

Tags: eclipse-rcp, headless, pde

Does anyone know of a good complete example (source, scripts, jobs)
that covers all the following?

- building an Eclipse RCP product with many features
- generating a P2 repository
- running JUnit tests
- using Eclipse 3.6.2
- building for few platforms with the Delta Pack

We are using the Headless PDE build system, but are open
to change to Buckminster or Maven.

Thanks,

Daniel Coupal

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Kai's MP3 Manager](https://max-server.myftp.org/trac/mp3m) and the associated [blog](http://www.toedter.com/blog/?p=458).

Answer (score 0):

Building with p2 for multiple platforms is fairly easy with eclipse 3.6.2.  By default, you get your RCP product, your features, a p2 repository, and multiple platform zips.  See http://pweclipse.blogspot.com/2010/09/simple-rcp-product-build.html for the main steps.

We use a masterBuild.sh bash [1] script to run our build, publish it, and then run our automated tests.  We copied the runtests [2] and test.xml [3] out of the standard Eclipse Test Framework [4].  See also [Automating unit tests (junit) for Eclipse Plugin development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255370/automating-unit-tests-junit-for-eclipse-plugin-development)

[1] http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/e4/releng/org.eclipse.e4.builder/scripts/masterBuild.sh?view=co&content-type=text%2Fplain

[2] http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/e4/releng/org.eclipse.e4.builder/builder/general/tests/runtests?view=co

[3] http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/e4/releng/org.eclipse.e4.builder/builder/general/tests/test.xml?view=co&content-type=text%2Fplain

[4] http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-Automation/automation.html