# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError for assertNotNull()

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

I don't have much experience on android JUnit test. Here I'm doing a simple test application for JUnit.The application contains two activity when the button pressed in the first activity Intent use to start the second activity.  But I'm getting `two failures` as `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError`. This is the code that I have tried:

```
public void testLayout(){
        buttonId=com.example.androidunittest.R.id.button;
        assertNotNull(activity.findViewById(buttonId));
        Button view=(Button) activity.findViewById(buttonId);
        assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button","Start",view.getText());
    }

    public void testIntentTriggerViaOnClick(){
        buttonId=com.example.androidunittest.R.id.button;
        Button view=(Button) activity.findViewById(buttonId);
        assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null",view);
            view.performClick();
            Intent triggeredIntent=getStartedActivityIntent();
        assertNotNull("Intent was null",triggeredIntent);
        String data=triggeredIntent.getExtras().getString("URL");

        assertEquals("Incorrect data passed via the intent","http://www.google.com", data);
}
```

The failure line are 
`assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null",view);`  and `assertNotNull(activity.findViewById(buttonId));` according to the JUnit test panel result.

Could anyone please explain me what is happening here? Also how to fix the error in the application code?

I have another question, how to run all test class once in eclipse?
 What I did is as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090280/running-junit-test-suite-from-inside-eclipse) , right click on the project -> Run as-> Android JUnit test. But only active class was gave the result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are following that SO answer, your Test method needs to be annotated with @Test.

Comment: So do I have to use @Test for all methods in test classes to run all of them once?

Comment: I believe with JUnit version 3 if you extended the TestCase class it would run all your test methods provided they also followed some sort of convention like public void testSomething(). But with Junit 4 (I think that's what you are using) you do not extend that class and annotate your test methods with @Test.

Comment: I'm following this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html. I did not use @Test for any method. when I tried to use it, it gave me an error. This is for android test case. I extend android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity>